# Making my first angular directive. 'vm' is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('contacts.directives')
    .directive('hotkeys', HotkeysDirective);

  HotkeysDirective.$inject = ['$resource', '$document'];

  function HotkeysDirective($resource, $document) {
    var directive = {
      templateUrl: '/my-app/contacts/client/views/ui/hotkeys.ui.html',
      link: link,
      controller: 'AddManagerController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        },
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

      $document.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (key == 1 || key == 2 || key == 3 || key == 4 || key == 5 || key == 6) {
          scope.$broadcast('keypress', e, e.which);
        }
      });

      scope.$on('keypress', function (event, key) {
        // do stuff
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
}());
```

This is the code that I think is not working...

```
HotkeysDirective.$inject = ['$resource', '$document'];

function HotkeysDirective($resource, $document) {
  var directive = {
    templateUrl: '/request-off-work/contacts/client/views/ui/hotkeys.ui.html',
    link: link,
    controller: 'AddManagerController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      },
  };

  return directive;

  function link(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
```

It's saying vm is undefined when I'm using controllerAs: 'vm', In the AddManagerController, it says 'var vm = this;'. Also not sure why scope: {} needs to be there, and I'll figure out bindToController eventually... I think I need to bind vm.credentials.groups to it.

Update: here's the controller

```
function AddManagerController($scope, $document, $rootScope, $state, $window, Authentication, ContactsService, Notification) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.authentication = Authentication;
  vm.credentials = {};
  vm.showGroups = [null, false, false, false, false, false, false];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use scope because you already bind to controller instance `this`.

Comment: Thank you! Still saying vm is undefined.. Edit: Does that mean I don't need scope in function link(scope, ... )?

Comment: No, I mean on directive definition, can u show me your html code.

Comment: <hotkeys></hotkeys>

Comment: $stateProvider
    .state('add-manager', {
      url: '/add-manager',
      templateUrl: '/my-app/contacts/client/views/add-manager.client.view.html',
      controller: 'AddManagerController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      data: {
        roles: ['user', 'admin']
      }
    })

Comment: As I saw html code, there is no Controller for `vm.showGroups`, go for this  solution `bindToController: true`

Comment: Getting closer... I updated it to show that showGroups is in the controller. Should probably include that in the directive

Comment: If I put vm.showGroups in the directive (instead of the controller), the buttons disappear :( And it says vm is undefined again

Comment: I saw your update now, just remove controller, controllerAs, scope, bindToController from your directive declaration, they seems not useful!

Comment: Do I have to inject vm into the directive? Still says vm is undefined. And thank you, I removed them :)

Comment: No you don't, you just have to use it on your `AddManagerController` controller!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146006/discussion-between-user6582640-and-lxhelili).

Answer (score 1):

You define a `controller` and a `controllerAs` equals to `vm`. Then you want to define a `bindToController = true` it means the directive bindings will be associated to the controller.

So if inside your controller you do:

```
this.myVar = 'test';
```

Then inside your directive's template you can simply do:

```
<div>{{vm.myVar}}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm going to make some edits and see if this answer fixes it.

Comment: {{vm.showGroups}} works... If I change vm.credentials.groups to this.credentials.groups it says cannot read 'credentials' of null

Comment: But are you typing inside the controller of the directive? Or the link function? And do you have at the beginning of the controller a line like `var vm=this;`

Comment: Thank you quirimmo. The first line of my controller says var vm = this;

Comment: yeah saw go on using inside your controller `vm.myVar = 'hello world';` and then inside your template `{{vm.myVar}}` and you should see hello wolrd

Comment: Yes, that works fine. But using console.log(vm.myVar) in the directive gives vm is not defined

Comment: do you mean inside your link function?

Comment: Yes sir, inside the link function.. hmm

Comment: nope my friend, inside the link you should use the reference to the controller, in your link function is called: `modelCtrl`. So you should do: `console.log(modelCtrl.myVar);` and it should work

Comment: Should I just change vm to scope? That seems to work with other controllers, but then I still don't understand why everyone always uses vm instead of $scope in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I changed vm.credentials.groups in the link function of the directive to scope.vm.credentials.groups and now it works. Hope this answer helps somebody.